# How to detect when screen goes on while screensaver is locked?

Tags: linux, kde, d-bus, screen-lock, screensaver

I am trying to execute `MyCommand` when the screen goes on while screensaver is locked in `KDE`, in two situations: when the screen is simply locked, and when the system is in suspend mode. Both are awaken by keyboard presses.

Of course I can make a loop while the screensaver is locked:

```
while [[ "`xset -q | grep -i "monitor is off"`" ]]; do sleep 1 ; done
MyCommand
```

and this will execute `MyCommand` when the screen turns on. But this is not elegant and consumes resources. There should be a way using `dbus-monitor`. I'm new to `dbus`, so I do not really know how it works.

I tried with

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.kde.KScreen'"

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.kde.screensaver'"

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver'"

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.kde.keyboard'"

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.kde.kwin'"
```

but neither one detects when the screen is turned on.